# About differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. While solving differential equations, is it okay to find an expression containing $y$ and $x$ (without $y'$) from which it's rather difficult to express $y$, for example, $$ \frac{\ln^2(y)}{y}-\frac{x}{y}= C?$$
2. Does it make sense to try to find $x(y)$ in some problems where it's easier?

Comment: certainly does. When you can find $x = x(y)$, for example, or even an implicit relationship $f(x,y)=0$ without derivatives, this is often a massive simplification to the ODE from which you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, it is typical to find the solution in a manner where $y$ and $x$ are implicitly defined.
2) Yes, in some cases it is easier to express $x=f(y)$ instead of $y=g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have a choice and this is a common situation.

For instance, in the case of a separable equation such as $g(y)\,dy=f(x)\,dx$, you are lucky if both members can be integrated analytically. Then you obtain a form like$$G(y)=F(x)+c$$ and you are even more lucky if $G$ is invertible analytically. It can arise that $G$ is not monotonic, and the solution must be split in several branches.